# Security of locked Android

Tags: security

I connected my Andriod phone to non-safety pc but phone was locked. Should I worry, Can pc install a malware to locked android phone?

Comment: Not in a modern Android device, if it is locked all it can do is charge, there is no file access unless you change it to MTP. Even then, if it copied a file to the device, you would have to open/install it for anything to happen. 99.99% chance you are fine and have no reason to worry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So even if copying occurs, It can't anything

Comment: Correct. Android has no provisions for automatically executing or opening a file. Plus, contrary to popular belief, hacking an Android device or pushing "malware" of any kind to it is nearly impossible without complete physical control of the device, including it's screen being unlocked (ie. knowing the PIN/password/pattern).

Answer (score 1):

If you have Android 6 or higher the PC cant harm your phone if:

1. Your phone hasnt USB-debugging enabled or the PC isnt trusted
2. The phone IS NOT in sideload or download mode
3. You didnt allowed MTP or any stuff like that